# Asserção com o Rspec

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Eu uso o framework Cucumber + Capybara + Ruby e não estou conseguindo realizar uma asserção usando o método “expect”.

Preciso por exemplo validar quatro mensagens retornadas no body, porem exibe erro:

Esperado: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"

Obtido: "qui est esse"

```
#encoding: utf-8
Given(/^I send a get to see four titles$/) do
    @api = HTTParty.get("https://jsonplcaholder.typicode.com/posts")
end

Then(/^Returned status code "(.*?)"$/) do |statuscode|
    expect(@api.code.to_s).to eq statuscode
end

Then(^Returnered message "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
    expect(@api[0]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[1]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[2]["title"]).to eq message
    expect(@api[3]["title"]).to eq message
end


Feature: message body
@titles
Scenario: Display of title all films
Given I send a get to see four titles
Then Returned status code "200"
Then Returned message "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
Then Returned message "qui est esse"
Then Returned message "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut"
Then Returned message "eum et est occaecati"

compared using ==
 RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
```

[image: arquivo backend11.rb]

[image: arquivo backend11.feature]

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você está tentado reaproveitar os steps, você precisa saber se quando o response voltar ele vai ter diversos objetos dentro dele.

Isso aqui:

```
Then(^Returnered message "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
  expect(@api[0]["title"]).to eq message
  expect(@api[1]["title"]).to eq message
  expect(@api[2]["title"]).to eq message
  expect(@api[3]["title"]).to eq message
end
```

Isso aqui valida o corpo do response inteiro, se na segunda asserção você não tiver o resto dos objetos não vai funcionar.

Por boa prática de escritas de cenários não se deve ter mais de um Then/Então, pois o seu cenário não fica atómico você acaba validando mais de uma coisa e cria muita responsabilidade. Cada cenário deve validar somente uma coisa, você poderia ter cenários que validam o schema outro que validam o conteúdo, mas nunca todos juntos.

O que está acontecendo é quando ele entra dentro do step ele não sabem quem vai validar e entra de novo no fluxo desde a posição 0 ele vai tentar dar um expect e não vai encontrar quem deveria.

Você poderia ter algo nessa linha:

```
Feature: message body
@status_code
Scenario: Display of title all films
Given I send a get to see four titles
Then Returned status code "200"

@titte
Scenario: Display of title all films
Given I send a get to see four titles
Then Returned message "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
```

E no seu step deveria ser uma única validação:

```
Then(^Returnered message "(.*?)"$/) do |message|
  expect(@api[0]["title"]).to eq message
end
```

Assim você manter uma complexidade menor e desacopla seus testes.

Eu recomendaria usar rspec + httparty o cucumber não foi criado para esse tipo de testes e sim para criar engajamento sobre funcionalidade e regras de negócio.